# map2 over columns and read .txt data into R storing as a list element

Tags: r, purrr

I have the following data:

```
                                                                                  folders                    Name
1              C:/Users/bscuser/Desktop/FactSet/FactSetData/zips/ref_hub_v2_full_1986.zip  econ_indicator_map.txt
2              C:/Users/bscuser/Desktop/FactSet/FactSetData/zips/ref_hub_v2_full_1986.zip entity_sub_type_map.txt
3   C:/Users/bscuser/Desktop/FactSet/FactSetData/zips/sym_merged_fsym_id_v1_full_4050.zip  sym_merged_fsym_id.txt
4 C:/Users/bscuser/Desktop/FactSet/FactSetData/zips/ent_supply_chain_hub_v1_full_2264.zip     ent_scr_address.txt
   Length                Date
1    1822 2021-07-03 01:48:00
2     925 2021-07-03 01:48:00
3 1180324 2021-07-03 01:26:00
4 4506085 2021-07-03 04:11:00
```

I would like to `map2` over the columns `folders` and `Name` and unzip the files in each zip folder.

So, in the folder `C:/Users/bscuser/Desktop/FactSet/FactSetData/zips/ref_hub_v2_full_1986.zip` (rows 1 and 2) it contains 2 `.txt` files that I would like to read in using `read.table`.

The following does not work.

```
zips %>% 
  map2(
    .x = folders,
    .y = Name,
    ~unz(.x, .y)
)
```

For a single observation, using the first row as an example I can run:

```
dataUnzipped <- unzip(zips[1, 1], list = TRUE, exdir = "unzipDumps")
```

Which gives me:

```
                      Name  Length                Date
1         hts_code_map.txt 5036228 2021-07-03 01:48:00
2 state_prov_coord_map.txt  117121 2021-07-03 01:48:00
3     mic_exchange_map.txt   47269 2021-07-03 01:48:00
4   state_province_map.txt  108424 2021-07-03 01:48:00
5              sic_map.txt   50354 2021-07-03 01:48:00
6           naics6_map.txt   50964 2021-07-03 01:48:00
```

I then run:

```
unzFile <- unz(zips[1, 1], dataUnzipped[1, 1])
```

Where `zips[1, 1]` is `"C:/Users/bscuser/Desktop/FactSet/FactSetData/zips/ref_hub_v2_full_1986.zip"` and `dataUnzipped[1, 1]` is `hts_code_map.txt`. This gives me:

```
A connection with                                                                                                         
description "C:/Users/bscuser/Desktop/FactSet/FactSetData/zips/ref_hub_v2_full_1986.zip:hts_code_map.txt"
class       "unz"                                                                                        
mode        "r"                                                                                          
text        "text"                                                                                       
opened      "closed"                                                                                     
can read    "yes"                                                                                        
can write   "yes"
```

Then I can run `read.table` to give the following:

```
> read.table(unzFile, sep = "|")
            V1             V2
1     HTS_CODE       HTS_DESC
2   0000000000  NONE PROVIDED
3   0000010000 NONE DISCLOSED
4   0000020000 NONE DISCLOSED
5   0000030000 NONE DISCLOSED
```

So how can I `map` over each of the rows and read in the `.txt` data?

Data:

```
zips <- structure(list(folders = c("C:/Users/bscuser/Desktop/FactSet/FactSetData/zips/ref_hub_v2_full_1986.zip", 
"C:/Users/bscuser/Desktop/FactSet/FactSetData/zips/ref_hub_v2_full_1986.zip", 
"C:/Users/bscuser/Desktop/FactSet/FactSetData/zips/sym_merged_fsym_id_v1_full_4050.zip", 
"C:/Users/bscuser/Desktop/FactSet/FactSetData/zips/ent_supply_chain_hub_v1_full_2264.zip"
), Name = c("econ_indicator_map.txt", "entity_sub_type_map.txt", 
"sym_merged_fsym_id.txt", "ent_scr_address.txt"), Length = c(1822, 
925, 1180324, 4506085), Date = structure(c(1625276880, 1625276880, 
1625275560, 1625285460), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"))), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Comment: Does this work? `map2(zips$folders,zips$Name,unz)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
library(tidyverse)
map2_df(zips$folders, zips$Name, function(x, y) {
  file <- unz(x, y)
  out <- read.table(unzFile, sep = "|", header = TRUE) # seems you have a header in your example
  out$source_file <- y
  return(out)
})
```

This should give you a nice `data.frame` with a column that tells you where each row came from (`source_file`). Assuming that the files can be bound together. Otherwise, just replace `map2_df` with `map2` and you'll get a list of `data.frame`s.